# Find records which contain a string starting and ending with certain characters

Tags: command-line

I need a command (preferably using `awk`) which lists the unique roll number and names of all students whose names starts with `A` and ends with `k` from the following list:

```
001 Abhishek Physics 90
002 Rohan Maths 100
003 simashree Chemistry 89
002 Rohan Language 80
005 Vamsi Computers 99
001 Abhishek Maths 95
006 Surjya Computers 93
```

Comment: All editors - given that the OP requested an `awk` command then this critical part of the question should remain in the question.

Comment: What is this, some kind of homework question? Check the edit history, the original sounds like textbook copy.

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked specifically for a solution using `awk`, then assuming the roll number and name are the first and second fields, you could use

```
awk '$2 ~ /^A[[:alpha:]]*k$/ {print $1,$2}' yourfile
```

If you need unique records, the easiest way is to pipe the results through the `sort -u` command

```
awk '$2 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]*k$/ {print $1,$2}' yourfile | sort -u
```

It may be more correct to use *word anchors* instead of *line anchors* ^, $ in the regular expression i.e.

```
awk '$2 ~ /\<[[:alpha:]]*k\>/ {print $1,$2}' ...
```

Both seem to work in this context (possibly because the field is whitespace separated already).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have those records in a file called `data_file.txt`, you can use:

```
grep "A[a-z]*k" data_file.txt
```

If you want to remove first column of numbers, then use:

```
grep "A[a-z]*k" test | cut -d" " -f 2-
```

If you want to remove last column of numbers, then use:

```
grep "A[a-z]*k" test | cut -d" " -f -3
```